# ¿Como puedo poner un contador aquí?

Tags: php

```
$pdf = new PDF_Proyectos();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(10,6,'#',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Nombres',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Apellidos',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(35,6,'Proyecto',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(35,6,('Encargado'),1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(35,6,('Lugar'),1,1,'C',1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $pdf->SetX(20);
        $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['#'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,utf8_decode($row['nombres']),1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,utf8_decode($row['apellidos']),1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(35,6,utf8_decode($row['nombre']),1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(35,6,utf8_decode($row['encargado']),1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(35,6,utf8_decode($row['lugar']),1,0,'C');
    }

$pdf->Output();
```

Quiero que en el campo $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['#'],1,0,'C'); me muestre un numero consecutivo como 1, 2, 3 en cada fila de la tabla generada, sé que se puede con un bucle pero no logro hacer que me funcione, agradezco toda ayuda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear un contador o un numero consecutivo con `while` puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$i = 0; // iniciamos el contador

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
    // ....

    // insertamos el contador con pre-incremento "++$i"
    $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row[++$i],1,0,'C');

   // ....
}
```

[+ info: Operadores de incremento/decremento](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.increment.php)